# WinJS IndexedDB implementation - how to use same DB as application version changes

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs, indexeddb

I am building a WinJS Metro app which will run in Surface and ther Win8 Tablets. Using IndexedDB to store local data before sending to server.
For distributing, we will probably use SideLoading or enterprise distribution and avoid Store. 
For testing I am creating APP Packages and sending to my co-workers.
**Problem 1**: Everytime I install app-package, it re creates the database and objectstore while I want to use existing database and object store for retaining old data.
**Problem 2** - My intent is to create a structure of objectstore, bundle some master data and distribute along with install package. I can somewhat achieve that now through code but can't separate out db components.
**Problem 3** - I am yet to find a good indexed db viewer for win8 where i can view all db, objectstores, structure and data.

thanks in advance ...

Comment: Are you saying that when you side Love Version B over Version A, it blows away the indexedDB state? That /shouldn't/ happen. You're just add-appxpackaging over the top, right? If you do that, you should be fine.

Comment: Yes - I am just doing add-appx...
However in code, I am doing an OpenDB to version 1. And then in the onupgradeneeded I initialize the objectstore ... like

dbRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (evt) { dbVersionUpgrade(evt); };

I was in an impression that this code executes only initially when db is created. Looks like it does everytime when a new version is released and installed !

Am I doing something grossly wrong here ?

Comment: If you open the DB with a version that isn't current, you'll be called to do the "upgrade".

Answer (score 1):

I have written a lib around the indexeddb, containing a kind of viewer inside to debug. You can find it on codeplex: [linq2indexed](http://linq2indexeddb.codeplex.com). It also comes with a nuget package. I also wrote a [post](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/07/linq2indexeddb-debugging-indexeddb.html) on how to use it.

I also have a viewer which works for the web, but haven't ported it to windows 8. Maybe you can give it a shot, I don't think it will be hard to do. You can also find the viewer trough nuget en on codeplex. For more information about the viewer take a look at this [post](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/11/indexeddbviewer-take-look-inside-your.html).

I hope this can help you further. Any comments, improvements, ... are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

So there's a few problems you're trying to solve here:

### Problem 1

With side-loading an app it will create a new app install which in turn creates a new path which the app is served off. Since IndexedDB is tied to the *domain* of the application it will be trashed (WinJS is a bit special since it's technically not a new domain but it's a new location that it's served from none the less).

From my understanding the way the Store will install an app won't trigger this, due to the way the application package is updated. Unfortunately I think this is a problem you're not going to be able to avoid side-loading packages.

### Problem 2

Microsoft actually provided a UI for debugging IndexedDB (it's a small JS library) which was on [their blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/01/25/debugging-indexeddb-applications.aspx). I personally haven't used it but it'd be a good starting point if there's no other wrapper out there that works for you.

### Problem 3

To do the initial database load I would have the following process:

- Listen for the `onupgradeneeded` event
- In the event handler read in a JSON file that was provided with the app, or embed the data in the JS file (depending on size)

This way you can have different versions of the data for different versions of your database (and even app).

Answer (score 0):

To "pre-bundle" indexed DB data, I would suggest that you create a bulk importer that loads the data from disk in JSON format, and then just iterate over it, adding the data as you need it. Kristof's linq2indexed, or my [db.js](http://github.com/grork/db.js) iteration would work well for this.

Comment: Thanks guys ... that would be my next step. But right now my problem is - data is not accessible as I install new version (new app package)

Answer (score 0):

looks like indexedDB instance is attached to release of an app. For example, in same machine (my dev box) I have a version 1.0.0.5 and 1.0.0.7. Both uses different indexeddb store and different set of data. also of I uninstall any version related db also gets un installed.
Also I think I can't install same version in overwrite mode (please correct me if I am wrong).
While I do understand underlying logic of such implementation, but this essentially means that I can't release patches to the my app as persistent data will be initialized in that case.

Can I do that using SQLite ? If yes, I need to follow that route ...